# Swift - Mix of Custom and default TableView Headers

Tags: swift, uitableview

In a tableview I'd like 1 custom header and the rest to be the default style, but I'm unsure how to specify the default header. So far I have:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if section == 1 {
            self.view.addSubview(viewDimensionHeader)
            return viewDimensionHeader // Works great

        } else {
            let view = UIView() // Not sure how to return default section header
            return view
        }
    }
```

The custom header works fine. Just looking for what to call to use the standard header.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return an instance of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` to get the default header/footer.  You can then set background/text etc on the standard view.

Note: you really should register all header and footer views with the tableView (as you do for tableView cells):

`tableView.register(viewDimensionHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CustomHeaderCell")`

and then you can dequeue (reuse) them for performance gains:

`let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CustomHeaderCell")`

Also note that you shouldn't add the header view as a subView of the main view - the tableView will take care of that for you, adding it as its own subView.  Just return the cell.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the tip on registering, and the addSubview was mentioned somewhere else but I'll get rid of that too. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Design cells in your Tableview Like attached screenshot and then use which ever cell you want in header:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell") as! CartOrderHeaderTableViewCell
    cell.packageNameLabel.text = self.tableArray[section].package ?? "N/A"
    return cell.contentView
}
```

This is the simplest way to use custom cells and different cells in UITableView
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply however you have misunderstood the question which was how to use the default / system header. Answered above with `return UITableViewHeaderFooterView()`